Understanding Feature Capture in Vision Transformers compared to CNN-based Networks like ResNets
I'm delving into the realm of computer vision and I'm particularly interested in understanding how Vision Transformers (ViTs) create features compared to Convolutional Neural Networks (CNNs), such as ResNet architectures.
I've been reading about ViTs and how they operate on sequences of image patches, using self-attention mechanisms to capture global dependencies. However, I'm still unclear about how do ViTs capture low-level and high-level features in images? How is this different from the feature extraction process in CNNs like ResNets?
I'd appreciate any insights, references to relevant papers or articles, or personal experiences that shed light on these comparisons. Understanding these nuances will greatly aid my decision-making process when choosing a model architecture for my computer vision projects.
There are so many resources online that it is hard to discriminate, aside from the original paper which I already studied, so a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.
